# prove this :$\sum_1^{100} A_i = \sum_0^{99} C_i $

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

In a class there are 100 student. We define $A_i$  as the number of friends of $ i^{th}$ student and $C_i$ as the number of students who has at least $i$ friends.

Prove that:
$\sum_1^{100} A_i = \sum_0^{99} C_i$

Comment: Use dollar signs to enclose math equations.

Comment: The summation on the right seems to need to start from one, not start from zero.  Consider the case where all students are not friends.  LHS = 0, meanwhile $C_0 = 100$ so RHS = 100.  Starting the summation from one seems to fix this issue.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry , that's my mistake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Making the correction that the sum on the RHS should start from one instead of from zero:

Consider the number of times a specific student contributes to the sum on the RHS.

If a student has $i$ friends, then he will contribute one to the total in $C_1$, again in $C_2$, again in $C_3$, up until again in $C_i$.  I.e. it will contribute a total of $i$ to the overall sum (broken up over multiple parts of the summation).

The result follows immediately from that observation.

---

If that wasn't descriptive enough, consider it this way: let $\chi_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 1&\text{if student}~i~\text{has at least}~j~\text{friends}\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

We have then the total sum is equal to:

$$\begin{array}{cccccc} \chi_{1,1}&+\chi_{1,2}&+\chi_{1,3}&+\chi_{1,4}&+\dots\\
\chi_{2,1}&+\chi_{2,2}&+\chi_{2,3}&+\dots\\
\chi_{3,1}&+\chi_{3,2}&+\dots\\
\vdots&&&\ddots\end{array}$$

Notice that $A_i$ is equal to the sum of the $i^{th}$ row whereas $C_j$ is equal to the sum of the $j^{th}$ column.  Stopping at $99$ for the sum for $C_j$ is fine since $C_{100}=0$ since noone can possibly be friends with $100$ people (there are only $99$ people for each person to be friends with).

So, the LHS summation is adding everything row by row whereas the RHS summation is adding everything column by column.

Comment: awesome explanation! Understood every word of it.......... thanks a lot @JMoravitz

Comment: hey so should I consider the question given in the book to be wrong?? @JMoravitz

Comment: @matrikashukla or perhaps the book uses a different interpretation of the phrase "*at least*" (*or there are translation issues at hand*).  I interpret it as having equal to or greater.  It might interpret it as having *strictly greater*.  With the interpretation as strictly greater, no change is necessary.

Comment: @matrikashukla another possibility that would fix the issue without needing to change the limits is the additional hypothesis that "everyone has at least one friend"

Comment: in the book it starts off with 0 (confirmed)........ but still according to me "at least" would mean greater than or equal to...........so ur proof serves the right purpose. Thanks! @JMoravitz